# OpenGL blending renders black on black as gray?

Tags: opengl-es, webgl, shader, blending

I'm working in webGL. I'm pretty new to OpenGL. Having trouble with the blending function. My options look like:

```
gl.enable(gl.BLEND)
gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
```

I render a source rectangle with color `[0,0,0,0.5]` on top of a destination background with color `[0,0,0,1]`. Based on everything I've read, I expect the result to be black. Instead it looks to be about 25% white. Here's what I get when I render [red and black rectangles with alpha values ranging from 0.0 to 1.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uauPk.png).

[View live demo and source here](https://unifac.googlecode.com/hg/tests/webgl/blend.html). Am I misunderstanding the blending function, and if so, how do I get what I expect? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Blending with HTML background in WebGL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11521035/blending-with-html-background-in-webgl)

Comment: Yep, that's it! It's setting the canvas itself transparent which renders the background color. I'm able to fix it by setting the canvas style to `background: black`. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You should specify separate function for alpha:

```
gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
gl.blendEquation(gl.FUNC_ADD);
gl.blendFuncSeparate(
    gl.SRC_ALPHA,
    gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA,
    gl.ONE,
    gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA
);
```

Comment: That worked straight up, I don't understand why it's not upvoted more